# SSRS - Enable and disable Windows integrated security

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

- I want to disable Windows integrated security on a report server and i had a look on that doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/turn-reporting-services-features-on-or-off#WinIntSec

  on the `Windows Integrated Security` section

My problem is that when i am right clicking on the report server , the properties option is not available.

Please see below screenshot .

Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: you you connected as a user with admin rights to the sql server instance?

Comment: Make sure you run SQL Server Management Studio as administrator too